# error: no matching function for call to second::second, candidates are: second::second(

Tags: c++, inheritance

I need to return the proper type as per the templatized argument. I am getting error as below:
Can someone please suggest whats the solution for this? Thanks in advance.

```
error: no matching function for call to âsecond::second(const std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)â
note: candidates are: second::second(const std::string&, const std::string&)
note:                 second::second(const second&)
```

Code is as below:

```
struct first
{
public:
    const string &str;
    first(const string & str) : str(str)     {    }
};

struct second : public first
{
public:
    const string &str2;
    second(const string &str1, const string &str2) : first(str1), str2(str2)
    {    }
};

class base
{
public:
    template<class T>
    inline T fun(const string &s1, const string &s2);//     { cout<<" T = "<<a;    }
};

template<class T>
inline T  base::fun(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    if(1)
        return T(s1);
    else
        return T(s1, s2);
}


int main()
{
    string a = "a";
    string bb = "b";
    base b;
    b.fun<first>(a, bb);
    b.fun<second>(a, bb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function `base::fun` needs to be compilable for all types of `T`. You will need to specialise the `base::fun` to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't create a function template which always accepts two arguments of fixed types, and returns objects of different types depending on template parameter. The reason is that you can't specialize template functions, you can only overload them, and you can't make overloaded functions differ only by return type.

What you can do is use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). This way at most one function will be present for given template parameter:

```
class base {
public:
    template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, first>::value>::type> 
    first fun(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
        return first(s1);
    }

    template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, second>::value>::type> 
    second fun(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
        return second(s1, s2);
    }
};
```

Alternatively you can make `base` templated and specialize it:

```
template<typename T> class base;

template<> class base<first> {
public:
    static first fun(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
        return first(s1);
    }
};

template<> class base<second> {
public:
    static second fun(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
        return second(s1, s2);
    }
};

base<first>::fun(a, bb);
base<second>::fun(a, bb);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c0692677024dba7)